# Ordered iteration in an user-defined aggregate function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I just implemented the ODCIAggregate Interface to create a custom aggregation function. It works quite well and fast, but I would like it to do a little something more. I have a statement going like this:

```
SELECT SomeId, myAggregationFunction(Item) FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Foo.SomeId, 
    SomeType(Foo.SomeValue, Foo.SomeOtherValue) AS Item
  FROM
    Foo
  ORDER BY Foo.SomeOrderingValue
)
GROUP BY SomeId;
```

My problem is that items aren't passed to the ODCIAggregateIterate function of my implementation in the same order that my inner (ordered) SELECT returns them.

I've Googled around and didn't find any Oracle-provided way to do so. Has any of you experimented a similar problem based on that requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: so you need the values in your `myAggregationFunction` to be ordered? why?

Comment: couldn't you `ORDER BY` the outer `SELECT`?

Comment: @Frank - Could your aggregate function store the data and then sort it before returning?  That's the most common solution if you want the function to operate on sorted input.

Comment: Cause the agregation function builds a mathematic equation from a table of terms and then evaluates it. Therefore, I need those terms to be agregated in the corect order to respect operators priority.

Comment: @Justin This is my alternative in case I don't find anything simpler/more performant. We'll see

Comment: Taking the order in which Oracle evaluates the rows in a SELECT as a dependency probably isn't reasonable. You'll likely need use a cursor solution and live with the performance.

Comment: @Conrad You're right. I realized also that it's kind of wrong to implement an aggregate function that **requires** an order. My case is not a real aggregation need. It's a little more than that. jonearles's answer below is what should be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using COLLECT instead of data cartridge?

At least for string aggregation, the COLLECT method is simpler and much faster.  It does make your SQL a little weirder though.

Below is an example using just simple string concatenation.

```
--Create a type
create or replace type sometype as object
(
    someValue varchar2(100),
    someOtherValue varchar2(100)
);

--Create a nested table of the type.
--This is where the performance improvement comes from - Oracle can aggregate
--the types in SQL using COLLECT, and then can process all the values at once.
--This significantly reduces the context switches between SQL and PL/SQL, which
--are usually more expensive than the actual work.
create or replace type sometypes as table of sometype;

--Process all the data (it's already been sorted before it gets here)
create or replace function myAggregationFunction(p_sometypes in sometypes)
return varchar2 is
    v_result varchar2(4000);
begin
    --Loop through the nested table, just concatenate everything for testing.
    --Assumes a dense nested table
    for i in 1 .. p_sometypes.count loop
        v_result := v_result || ',' ||
            p_sometypes(i).someValue || '+' || p_sometypes(i).someOtherValue;
    end loop;

    --Remove the first delimeter, return value
    return substr(v_result, 2);
end;
/

--SQL
select someId
    ,myAggregationFunction
    (
        cast
        (
            --Here's where the aggregation and ordering happen
            collect(sometype(SomeValue, SomeOtherValue)
                order by SomeOrderingValue)
            as someTypes
        )
    ) result
from
(
    --Test data: note the unordered SoemOrderingValue.
    select 1 someId, 3 SomeOrderingValue, '3' SomeValue, '3' SomeOtherValue
    from dual union all
    select 1 someId, 1 SomeOrderingValue, '1' SomeValue, '1' SomeOtherValue
    from dual union all
    select 1 someId, 2 SomeOrderingValue, '2' SomeValue, '2' SomeOtherValue
    from dual
) foo
group by someId;

--Here are the results, aggregated and ordered.
SOMEID  RESULT
------  ------
1       1+1,2+2,3+3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's definitely the best way to do that. In the meantime, I did what Justin suggested in the comments of the question, wich works fine, but I think your way is cleaner. COLLECT function is now part of my toolbox ;) Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Well thought. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Oracle is very likely be rewriting your query and getting rid of the subquery. I've never done anything like what you're doing, but could you add the `NO_UNNEST` hint on the inner query?

```
SELECT SomeId, myAggregationFunction(Item) FROM
(
  SELECT /*+ NO_UNNEST */
    Foo.SomeId, ...
```

Even then, I'm really not sure what it will do with an ORDER BY inside a subquery.